# Python Incorrectly Creating Aggregated QR Codes From CSV Data

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, csv, qr-code

I have a Python script that I thought was working fine at first; it basically creates a folder for an organization, grabs a csv, and uses the first column of that csv to create QR codes (concatenated with the organization name), which it stores in the 'image' folder for that organization.

Here's the script:

```
import csv
import qrcode
import os

org = "1234"
filename = '/Users/Ryan/Download/test.csv'
localfolder = '/Users/Ryan/Download/'+org
localimagefolder = localfolder+'/image'

if not os.path.exists(localfolder):
    os.makedirs(localfolder)
if not os.path.exists(localimagefolder):
    os.makedirs(localimagefolder)

with open(filename, 'rU') as csvfile:
    next(csvfile, None) #skip header row
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', dialect=csv.excel_tab)

    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
        box_size=10,
        border=4,
    )

    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        labeldata = row[0] #Choose first column of data to create QR codes
        print labeldata

        qr.add_data(org+"-"+labeldata)
        qr.make()

        img = qr.make_image()
        img.save(localimagefolder+"/"+org+"-"+labeldata+".png".format(i)) #Save image
```

The test.csv is literally just a three column file that looks like this:

```
ID      FirstName      LastName
813     Aaron          Zobrist
64      Adam           Young
871     Alana          Yarnell
728     Alexandra      Wilson
980     Ali            Williams
118     Alicia         Wilderman
51      Alonzo         Wilcox
902     Alphonso       Whitehouse
915     Amanda         Wharton
```

Good enough for my purposes to just create a QR code based on the org variable in the script with the person's primary ID. Everything should work well if you run that script -- except that when you actually read the QR codes, all those IDs are aggregated together instead of individually.

This is the first QR code (ID: 813) from the file which returns a perfect result (1234-813). But it only returns the right code because it's the first one:

[image: here]

Here's the last one (ID: 915) that seems to incorrectly incorporate all the other IDs as well (as you can also see from the size):

[image]

When you read this code, the return is "1234-8131234-641234-8711234-7281234-9801234-1181234-511234-9021234-915" instead of what it should be: "1234-915".

Hopefully this is just a dumb error I can't find in my script. Can anyone help here? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that `qr.add_data()` will add data to your existing `qr`. It would make more sense to structure your code as follows:

```
import csv
import qrcode
import os

org = "1234"
filename = '/Users/Ryan/Download/test.csv'
localfolder = '/Users/Ryan/Download/'+org
localimagefolder = localfolder+'/image'

if not os.path.exists(localfolder):
    os.makedirs(localfolder)
if not os.path.exists(localimagefolder):
    os.makedirs(localimagefolder)

with open(filename, 'rU') as csvfile:
    next(csvfile, None) #skip header row
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', dialect=csv.excel_tab)

    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        labeldata = row[0] #Choose first column of data to create QR codes
        print labeldata

        qr = qrcode.QRCode(
            version=1,
            error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
            box_size=10,
            border=4,
        )

        qr.add_data(org+"-"+labeldata)
        qr.make()

        img = qr.make_image()
        img.save(localimagefolder+"/"+org+"-"+labeldata+".png".format(i)) #Save image
```

By doing this, you will be working with a new `QRCode()` object on each iteration of your loop.